# What happens to the unix/mac file ownership/group/permissions when it is copied or moved to a different system

Tags: macos, unix

Talking about Mac specifically or perhaps Unix I am bit confused about how file ownership/group when a file is moved from one system to another.

For example On my mac if I create a file I am the owner of it, so let's say the owner is 'ahmed' and group is 'staff'

When this file is copied to another macbook, will the user 'ahmed' still be the owner and the group be 'staff' ? even though on second macbook the user 'ahmed' or group 'staff' may or may not exist. ?

Can someone please explain, its quite confusing.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply copy files without asking the o/s to retain the permissions (usually a -p flag to 'cp') then the files that get copied are re-created on the target area owned by the user that issued the copy.  For example, if I (freudy) copied a file that was owned by Ahmed in /tmp to my home directory:

```
cp /tmp/ahmedsFile .
```

Then I (freudy) would own the copy.

To retain ownership type permissions across users, I suspect you're going to need to be **root**.

so,

```
sudo su -
cp -p /tmp/ahmedsFile /home/freudy
```

Would result in /home/freudy/ahmedsFile being owned by Ahmed.

Note, this is all on same machine to illustrate the point behind retaining permissions (ownership and file attributes).

As already noted, the userid's and groupdid's are stored numerically in the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files. Copying files between systems (whilst preserving the file permissions) with different id's will result in the copies being 'owned' by different users.

```
Source Machine Passwd
testuser:x:1001:1001:Test user:/home/testuser:/bin/sh

Target Machine Passwd
rupert:x:1001:1001:Rupert the bear:/home/rupert:/bin/sh
```

Copying from source to target whilst preserving permissions will have any files that were apparently owned by 'testuser' on the source, appearing to be owned by 'rupert' on the target.  This is commonly a problem when restoring archive files (i.e. tar files) as tar stores id's in the same way as the o/s does.

Archiving files into tar on the source machine, and extracting on the target will demonstrate the username switch.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, For case 1 what group is applied to the file if permissions are not retained, primary group of user ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how the files are copied but almost certainly no. If, for example, you copy the files using `scp`:

```
ahmed@macbook$ scp foo.txt remoteuser@remotemachine:/home/remoteuser/
```

this will create a new file owned by `remoteuser`. In order to copy a file to a new machine, you need to somehow get access to the new machine. This means you will have to log into the new machine with some kind of user name. Copying files means creating new ones on the new machine, these are data, not physical objects so you are not actually moving anything around. Since you will be creating new files, normal rules for file creation apply.

Comment: So the process that creates a file on the new system, whatever useraccount it is running under, that user will be the owner correct ? what about group ? primary group of that process's user on this other machien ?

Comment: @Ahmed yes, on both counts.

Answer (score 0):

Unix file and group ownership is not coded with the names but with numeric ids within the filesystem. These are translated to the names with /etc/passwd and /etc/group. If you move a disk to another system and that system hast different names for those ids the owner will change. If the ids are not used at all, ownership will usually be displayed as the numeric ids. If you later add a user/group with that id, s/he will own the files.

Comment: Does your answer still apply if only files are copied not the disk moved to a new system ? is this ownership/group/permission information stored within each file itself or does the file system has a separate file to owner map elsewhere ?

Comment: The filesystem has no map, only the operating system with /etc/passwd and /etc/group or in companies mapping services like LDAP or Active Diretory. If you copy a file over the network, it depends on the method. If you use scp or SMB/Samba, the new owner is the user you log in as on the remote machine. If you use nfs version 3 then the numerical ids apply as above. With nfs version 4 optionally the names are matched if they exist.